# Using moment.js with Ember, Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have been trying to get the moment.js library to work with an Ember application using the Ember-cli. Note I am fairly new to ES2015.

Ember 2.2.0
Ember-cli 1.13.13

my ember-cli-build

```
/*jshint node:true*/
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
    var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
        //options
    });

    app.import('bower_components/moment/moment.js');

    return app.toTree();
};
```

and my .jshintrc

```
"predef": [
    "document",
    "window",
    "-Promise",
      "moment"
  ],
```

and my controller

```
/* global moment:true */
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    day: function () {
        return moment('Dec 25, 1995');
    }.property()
});
```

I always get an error that 'moment' has not been defined. I read that the latest moment.js has stopped producing a global 'moment' but I'm not sure what to do about it.

The builds work. If I pull up the generated vendor.js I can see the complete contents of the moment.js file in it. However when I look at vendor.js in the chrome debugger the contents are omitted. I wasn't sure if this was due to some optimization.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you could try `import moment from 'bower_components/moment/moment.js';`. If moment.js now use ES6-Modules this should work. (And I'm curious myself)

Comment: I think you got your globals wrong it should be `/* global moment */`, so you might be getting just jshint warnings

Comment: just for fun I tried @Jeff's suggestion, I was curious as well... this produced an error on the route Error while processing route: index Could not find module `bower_components/moment/moment.js` imported from `es2015-test/controllers/application` Error: Could not find module `bower_components/moment/moment.js` imported from `es2015-test/controllers/application`

Comment: @bek it turns out that I had it working.. and for the record both /* global moment */ and /* global moment:true */ work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the best way to install `moment.js` in ember app is to use [ember moment addon](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment)
after installing it you will be able to use it as

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

plus you will get various `helpers`

Comment: It turns out that I had it working with these settings!... the issue was that I had been making changes while the "ember serve" was running and for some reason it wouldn't pick up the import. I had to completely stop the server. However I guess I'll mark this as an answer since its a better way to go anyway.